# Is there a value that has a type of Show Int?

Tags: typeclass, idris

According to idris `Show Int` is a type.

```
*main> :t Show Int
Show Int : Type
```

What is of an example of a value that has that type?

```
*main> :t ?
? : Show Int
```

What could I replace `?` with to get that behavior?

I found the answer to my question here: [In Idris, is "Eq a" a type, and can I supply a value for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339586/in-idris-is-eq-a-a-type-and-can-i-supply-a-value-for-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is this single instance of the `Show` typeclass

```
Show String where
show cs = strCons '"' (showLitString (cast cs) "\"")
```

defined in `Prelude/Show.idr` where the typeclass is also defined

Comment: After reading your answer I am still not sure what values if any have a type of `Show Int`. I understand how type classes work in Haskell. In Haskell `Show` is a `* -> Constraint` (which makes sense to me) but in Idris `Show` is `Type -> Type` (which confuses me).

Comment: http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html

Maybe this helps: Show String is the implementation and hence value of the interface Show: Type -> Type

Comment: AFAIK you can't ask the REPL for that. Implementations for interfaces are a bit different to normal instances of Types, as the compiler makes sure that there is always only one of them. You can however give implementations a name: http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#named-implementations

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44347094/6369276

Comment: Thanks for sharing, nice trick!
` :t {auto inst: Show String} -> Show String` is almost what you wanted. For more my idris foo is not sufficient.

Comment: you can also just use `%implementation` to run a search